# Delete Files with C++ on windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a C++ program and I want to have some created files deleted if meeting with some conditions. These file have various file names that are assigned  using type "string" in each iteration. Now I'm trying to delete some of the files with their file names, but it seems that neither **Deletefile** function nor **remove** can deal with C++ strings. I have also tried to convert the strings to c type char* but it doesn't work.

I'm using visual studio community 2015 on windows 10.

Is their any convenient way for this problem?

Comment: Did you try calling `c_str ()` method on the `std::string` object that you have?

Comment: Try c_str( ) method of the std::string/std::wstring for DeleteFileA/DeleteFileW. In Unicode Character Set - DeleteFile is equal to DeleteFileW, in Multi-Byte - to DeleteFileA.

Answer (score 10):

As said in the comment - the function `.c_str()` returns C-compatible string that can be use with `DeleteFile` and `remove`.

If that doesn't work, I'd guess that you app is compiled as Unicode , meaning you will have to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

try to combine the two ways:

```
std::string fileName = "C://file.txt";
std::wstring wFileName(fileName.begin(),fileName.end());
auto res = DeleteFile(wFileName.c_str());
```

`remove` however, uses "regular" `const char*`.

Comment: Thank you. DeleteFile doesn't work. remove method can pass the compiling but no file was deleted.

Comment: I see what the problem is. I cannot delete a file with its filestream open. Now that I use .close(), the files are successfully deleted. Thanks a lot, guys.